# How to run a QThread from QWizardPage and access field()

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qwizard, qwizardpage

I need some advice to access the field(`QString name`) variable in `QWizardPage` from a `QThread`. I'm building some kind of an installer and I want to do the installing work in a separate Thread.

My purpose: 
When reached the commit/install page, I want to execute code to do the "installing" and update the `QWizardPage` with my progress, until its finished.

The install function is dependent on many `field()` variables from other `QWizardPages`. Therefore I tried to execute this install function from a QThread, which is defined in an inner class from my `QWizardPage`. The problem is, the `field()`-function i a non-static member and so it's not working. And so I'm out of ideas to run my install-function parallel to my WizardPage.

I tried something like this:

```
InstallPage.h

class InstallPage : public QWizardPage
{
    Q_OBJECT
    class WorkerThread : public QThread
    {
        Q_OBJECT
        void run() override;
    };

public:
    InstallPage(QWidget *parent = 0);

private: 
    QLabel *lProgress;
    WorkerThread *installer;
    void install(); 
};


InstallPage.c

InstallPage::InstallPage(QWidget *parent)
    : QWizardPage(parent)
{
...
    installer = new WorkerThread(this);
    installer->start();
}

void InstallPage::WorkerThread::run()
{
    if(field("checkBox1").ToBool()) 
    {
         doStuff();
    }
}

//QT-Creator says at field("checkBox1"): 
//error: call to non-static member function without an object argument
```

I'm also open for any other idea to make my installer work. Maybe someone knows something I haven't thought of.

Comment: Like eyllaesc suggests, invert the dependency and create a separate worker class, copy the necessary information. Makes synchronization much easier, too.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to create a worker (QObject) that lives in another thread that performs the heavy task and notifies the status of that task through signals:

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets>

class InitialPage: public QWizardPage
{
public:
    InitialPage(QWidget *parent = nullptr): QWizardPage(parent)
    {
        QSpinBox *spinbox = new QSpinBox;
        QLineEdit *lineedit = new QLineEdit;
        QVBoxLayout *lay = new QVBoxLayout(this);
        lay->addWidget(spinbox);
        lay->addWidget(lineedit);

        registerField("value1", spinbox);
        registerField("value2", lineedit);
    }

};

class InstallWorker: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    InstallWorker(QObject *parent=nullptr): QObject(parent)
    {

    }
public Q_SLOTS:
    void install(int param1, const QString & param2)
    {
        Q_EMIT started();
        for(int i=0; i < 100; i++){
            qDebug() << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << i << param1 << param2;
            QThread::msleep(100);
            Q_EMIT progressChanged(i);
        }
        qDebug()<< __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "finished";
        Q_EMIT finished();
    }
Q_SIGNALS:
    void started();
    void progressChanged(int value);
    void finished();
};

class InstallPage: public QWizardPage
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    InstallPage(QWidget *parent = nullptr): QWizardPage(parent),
        label(new QLabel), progressbar(new QProgressBar)
    {

        QVBoxLayout *lay = new QVBoxLayout(this);
        lay->addWidget(label);
        lay->addWidget(progressbar);

        progressbar->setMinimum(0);
        progressbar->setMaximum(100);

        thread = new QThread(this);
        worker.moveToThread(thread);
        connect(&worker, &InstallWorker::started, this, &InstallPage::onStarted);
        connect(&worker, &InstallWorker::finished, this, &InstallPage::onFinished);
        connect(&worker, &InstallWorker::progressChanged, this, &InstallPage::onProgressChanged);
        thread->start();
    }
    ~InstallPage(){
        thread->quit();
        thread->wait();
    }
    void initializePage(){
        start_install();
    }
private Q_SLOTS:
    void start_install(){
        int param1 = field("value1").toInt();; 
        QString param2 = field("value2").toString();
        QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&worker, "install", Qt::QueuedConnection, Q_ARG(int, param1), Q_ARG(QString, param2));
    }
    void onStarted(){
        for(QWizard::WizardButton which: {QWizard::BackButton, QWizard::NextButton, QWizard::CancelButton})
            if(QAbstractButton * button = wizard()->button(which))
                button->setEnabled(false);
    }
    void onFinished(){
        for(QWizard::WizardButton which: {QWizard::BackButton, QWizard::NextButton, QWizard::CancelButton})
            if(QAbstractButton * button = wizard()->button(which))
                button->setEnabled(true);
        wizard()->next();
    }
    void onProgressChanged(int value){
        progressbar->setValue(value);
        label->setNum(value);
    }
private:
    InstallWorker worker;
    QThread *thread;
    QLabel *label;
    QProgressBar *progressbar;
};

class FinalPage: public QWizardPage
{
public:
    FinalPage(QWidget *parent = nullptr): QWizardPage(parent)
    {

    }
};

#include "main.moc"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QWizard wizard;
    wizard.addPage(new InitialPage);
    wizard.addPage(new InstallPage);
    wizard.addPage(new FinalPage);
    wizard.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: I tested it with some fields and this approach works well. But the problem I have with this is, that I have many fields, that are needed for installing. In your solution you pass the field-values as arguments to the thread. But I would need about 20-30 arguments there and this doesn't seems to be an elegant way to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Tiger69 Are they the same type? If they are then package it in a container so you only have to pass one arguments. If they are different you can convert it to QVariant and use a container as indicated